# Implement a CONTAINS (IN) in DB2?

Tags: database, db2

I have a DB2 9.X table with a column named summary.

Here's an example.

SUMMARY

updated www.name1.do.com

Went from www.there2.do.com towww.here1.do.com

Backed up theretherethere.do.this.com and restored to hellothereworld.go.com

Those are three different rows.

In my program I've got a list of URLs. I need to search the database in a way that returns all the rows if the summary column CONTAINS any of the URLs in my list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store your URLs in a table (i.e. urls) and put '%' round your urls (i.e. %www.name1.do.com%) join both table using a cross join and select like this:

```
select summary 
from basetable, urls
where summary like urls.likecolumn
```